# "Duplicate" flags shown as "helpful" ... but question not actually closed as duplicate?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions, flag-history

I'm confused by the flag status reporting for duplicate questions.

I flagged [a particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786280) as a potential duplicate. Normally (I think) such flags would be shown as "pending" on my [flag summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3195477). But instead, this one was shown as "helpful".

However when I look at the actual question, there has been no change. Its not closed as a duplicate. So what does the lack of "pending" and presence of "helpful" mean?

Comment: Meta SE FAQ: [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac)

Comment: The [close review on that post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/21297955) has not yet completed. But at least one of the reviewers agreed and also voted to close, and that's enough to mark your flag as helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Helpful" means that there was *someone* who voted to close in this case [that agreed with your close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253836). One *single* vote is all it takes to be marked as helpful; whether it's successfully *closed* isn't actually relevant.

As noted in [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105395/297415):

> Flags to close a question will be dismissed as helpful as soon as
>   another user votes to close it. However, if you don't have enough
>   reputation to see close votes, it will appear as if nothing has
>   happened until more users vote to close and the question is actually
>   closed.